Fastest x86 64 jump table. What are the methods for making very performance oriented jump table?
I am in the process of optimizing a program that interprets some byte code, and depending on it jumps to different instructions. Since we have the instruction in byte code already ordered from 0-17, we thought that it would be fastest to create a jump table and shift the instruction by 3. However after using numerous bench-marking tools we noticed that the biggest CPU time taker is the jump table (the precise instruction time was seen using perf). This program is single threaded.
This brought me down a rabbit hole of trying to find the fastest way to do this switch-case esque computation. For example I noticed doing a comparison with the most often seen instruction considerably sped up the program (>5%). But most resources I find are aimed toward C users and less assembly.
So that led me to create this question to ask which are my performance oriented options.
Again to reiterate my instructions are 0-17 (18 total) and they need to go to separate branches. From dynamic analysis there are virtually 0 cache/branch misses so that isn't the problem.
This is what my current table looks like:
.data
bytcodejmptable: #not actual names
  .quad bytecode1
  .quad bytecode2
  .quad bytecode3
  .quad bytecode4
  .quad bytecode5
  .quad bytecode6
  .quad bytecode7
  .quad bytecode8
  .quad bytecode9
  .quad bytecode10
  .quad bytecode11
  .quad bytecode12
  .quad bytecode13
  .quad bytecode14
  .quad bytecode15
  .quad bytecode16
  .quad bytecode17
  .quad bytecode18


#decoding code (bytecode is 32bits)
.macro decodenextinstruction
   movl (%r13),%r11d
   movl %r11d, %r12d
   shr $21, %r11 #move correct place and multiply by 8
   andl $0XFFFFFF, %r12d #0x00FFFFFF
   cmpq $16, %r11 
   je bytecodegoright
   jmp *bytcodejmptable(%r11)
.endm


Technical Info: I am using gcc to assemble (GAS syntax)

The fastest approach is to translate your bytecode to subroutine-threaded codeand avoid the jump table entirely.

What microarchitecture?  Haswell and later have IT-TAGE branch prediction which does ok with complex patterns for indirect branches.  (Also Zen 2 and later, IIRC).  Still not perfect for non-trivial code, of course.  Branch Prediction and the Performance of Interpreters - Don’t Trust Folklore (2015) / How does Branch Prediction affect performance in R?

If you have byte code and want to execute with real performance, then just go to (JIT) compilation.  There’ll be a virtually unlimited amount of optimizations you can do in a (JIT) compiler, but even a simple one will be leaps and bounds above interpreting.  Alternatively, just don’t worry about performance, knowing you can do compilation later.
